# SFML sf::Text::setFillColor is broken or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: c++, sfml

The code I've written displays the sf::Drawable objects only for the top state of the state stack. Rendering works fine for everything, except the sf::Text type, that does not change the color of the text when button.getText().setFillColor(sf::Color:Red) is called. However, when I construct a button with a red text, whenever I try to set another color to that button, I only get a white text, no matter what color I request.

Here's where I change the color of a button:

```
void GameState_MainMenu::handleRealTimeInput()
{
    for each (TextButton button in mButtons)
    {
        if (button.isSpriteClicked())
        {
            button.getText().setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
            button.triggerAction();
            sf::Clock wait;
            sf::Time timer = sf::Time::Zero;
            timer = sf::seconds(0.15f);
            while (wait.getElapsedTime() < timer)
            {

            }
            wait.restart();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my Game::render() method:

```
void Game::render()
{
    GameState *currentState = getActiveState();
    if (currentState != nullptr)
    {
        mWindow.clear();
        currentState->draw();
    }
    mWindow.display();
}
```

Lastly, this is the draw method of the MainMenu state:

```
void GameState_MainMenu::draw()
{
    game->mWindow.draw(game->mBackground);
    game->mWindow.draw(mSelector.mSprite);
    for each (TextButton button in mButtons)
    {
        game->mWindow.draw(button.getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: `for each` ? Is this C++ ?

Comment: yes, it's a c++ 11 feature(might be wrong).

Comment: Seems to be a MS specific thing from before the range based for loop was introduced in c++11: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182879/which-is-preferable-for-each-in-or-for-each.

Comment: Are you sure that `getText()` returns a reference?

Comment: @DarkPhantom Yes. sf::Text& TextButton::getText(){return mText;}

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you have a while loop in the GameState_MainMenu::handleRealTimeInput that the program is getting stuck in.

You can try to use threads, though that way could get pretty messy. I suggest revising your code.

Comment: the game doesn't get stuck, as it allows me to input data, such as keyboard movement data.

Comment: @ijustpostedsomethingdumb well, based on your code it seems to be different. Based upon what I see its hitting the while loop then stopping there.

Comment: @ijustpostedsomethingdumb there isn't enough information to make a suggestion after rereading this code.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I figured out this had something to do with c++'s for each instruction. As soon as I switched to the classic array-like traversal, my buttons started changing colors. I'm not saying this is THE solution, just that it worked for me. If anyone has the same problem, you might want to check that.