# IntelliSense Visual Studio 2010 SP1 unique_ptr : unique_ptr<vector<unique_ptr<T>>> T

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++11, intellisense

I searched to see if I find a solution to this problem but I was not able to see an answer. The problem that I'm having is while my code compiles, I don't get intellisense

if I'm receiving a parameter (or declaring a variable) such as this with template T :

```
unique_ptr<vector<unique_ptr<T>>> & dataSets;
```

intellisense finds dataSets.get() but it does not find dataSets.get()->clear(); however, it compiles fine if I do it. 
   However, if it not a template, it seems to work fine.

CODE:

```
    template <typename T> 
void mtsql::MTMySQL<T>::executePrepareStatement(const string & sqlText,const unique_ptr<vector<SQLDataType>> & argList,unique_ptr<vector<unique_ptr<T>>> & dataSets)
{
    dataSets.get()->clear();
    unique_ptr<sql::ResultSet> rs;
    for (auto iter = argList->cbegin(); iter != argList->cend() ; ++iter)
    {
        auto ps = this->createPreparedStatment(sqlText,args);
        rs.reset(ps->execute());
        dataSets.get()->insert(std::move(rs)); 
        ps.release();
    }

}
```

I'm new at c++11 so I may be doing extra steps or steps that may be wrong (for example, I think ps.release() is not needed... my point was to delete it, but since is a smart point)

Thanks for the help!

EDIT 1: 
Thanks to the help, my code looks much nicer and without possible leakage. 
Thank you!

```
    dataSets->clear();

for (auto iter = argList->cbegin(); iter != argList->cend() ; ++iter)
{
    auto ps = this->createPreparedStatment(sqlText,args);
    dataSets->push_back(std::move(rs));         
}
```

Comment: A a side note, you shouldn't have to do `dataSets.get()->clear()`, but simply `dataSets->clear()`, as `unique_ptr<T>` implements `operator ->()`.  It doesn't impact functionality, just readability.

Comment: And, assuming `ps` is some sort of unique_ptr, you might have a memory leak when you execute `ps.release()`, since that function tells unique_ptr to release control to the caller and will not call the destructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ is not a simple language to parse and semantic. Therefore you can't expect IntelliSense to work perfectly with complicated types.

As for your code, you could simplify the code to do:

```
dataSets->clear();  // no need to use `get` here.

for (auto& ignored : *argList) {  // use range-based for.
    auto ps = this->createPreparedStatment(sqlText,args);
    dataSets->insert(ps->execute());  // no need to define 'rs'.
    // no need to release explicitly, if they are indeed smart pointers.
}
```

(And if `dataSets` is really a `unique_ptr<vector<unique_ptr<T>>>` I think you should use `dataSets->push_back` instead of `insert`.)

---

Edit: [MSVC 2010 does not support range-based for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898859/does-msvc10-visual-studio-2010-support-c-range-based-loops). It does support lambdas though:

```
std::for_each(argList->cbegin(), argList->cend(), [&](const vector<SQLDataType>&) {
   auto ps = this->createPreparedStatment(sqlText,args);
   dataSets->insert(ps->execute());  // no need to define 'rs'.
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. for some reason, I don't think this is valid in vs 2010 for (auto& ignored : *argList). Thank you !!!

Comment: No, support for the range-for was added in Visual C++ 2012.  Visual C++ 2010 does not support it.

Answer (score 2):

IntelliSense for template parameters and dependent names in C++ is limited at best.

`T` can be *any type*.  There is no way for IntelliSense to accurately compute a common set of operations that are valid for all actual types with which your template will be instantiated.

Note that this problem affects dependent types too, not just to `T` itself, because `T` or the templates that you instantiate with `T` (like `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` in your example) may be explicitly specialized and those explicit specializations may have different members than the primary template.

From usage, it appears that it makes a best effort attempt to build a completions list for dependent names in some cases, but one should not be too surprised if this list is incomplete, empty, or incorrect.

Concepts, a feature proposed for C++11 but eventually dropped from the specification, would probably enable far better IntelliSense for template parameters and possibly for many dependent names.

Comment: This is a weakness in the C++ template systems that Concepts were aiming at solving by providing the set of usable operations on the type. With Concepts, IntelliSense could work in templated code :)