# Compilation error with "for each" loop in C++ VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, loops, visual-studio-2012, foreach

I was working on a little C++ project at home, which I brought into school to show my teacher. At home I have Visual Studio 2012, whereas the school computers have Visual Studio 2010. In my code, from home, I had a for loop, like so, which compiled:

```
for(char c : myStr){...}
```

However, when I tried it on my school's computers, it did not compile, and I ended up having to do this instead:

```
for each(char c in myStr){...}
```

Why is this the case?

Comment: Are you using the same version of `C++` in each?

Comment: The `for each` is syntax introduced with C++/CLI, but is available without it (still, a Microsoft specific extension).

Comment: @nhgrif - I was thinking that, but I couldn't check (we have very short lessons)

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 does not support as much of the current C++ standard as 2012.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx

Comment: See here, also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898859/does-msvc10-visual-studio-2010-support-c-range-based-loops

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `for(char c : myStr){...}` syntax is new with `C++11`, so anything using an older version of `C++` won't compile with that syntax.

Previous to C++11, `for_each` is defined in the `algorithm` header.

Answer (score 4):

C++11 range-based for loops aren't supported in Visual Studio 2010.

The second form is a syntax that leaked into the compiler from C++/CLI (an entirely different language that targets the .NET runtime).  I filled a bug on this a while back.  If you compile with the `/Za` switch, it will disable this language extension.  You will need to use the C++03 for loop syntax using an iterator or `std::for_each`.

Answer (score 4):

The "range for" is a C++ 11 feature that was [added in Visual Studio 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh409293%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). To learn more about which C++ 11 features are in Visual Studio 2008 (VC9) and Visual Studio 2010 (VC10), check [the blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/04/06/c-0x-core-language-features-in-vc10-the-table.aspx) from the Visual C++ team. There are similar tables to let you know about [Visual Studio 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx) and several different releases of [Visual Studio 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/12/02/c-11-14-core-language-features-in-vs-2013-and-the-nov-2013-ctp.aspx).

Bottom line: your `for` loop that you did at home is great if you have Visual Studio 2012. If you don't, use a regular `for` or `std::for_each`, not the `for each` you're using there.

Answer (score 3):

Foreach loop was introduced in the C++11 standard, the compilers at your school probably aren't up to date with the new standard.

Answer (score 3):

MS VC++ 2010 was released before the C++ 2011 Standard was adopted. So it does not support the range-based for statement. On the other hand MS VC++ 2010 has MS language extension for-each-in that was introduced in managed C++ to support foreach statement of C#.

Answer (score 2):

The for(char c: myStr) syntax is one of the new C++11 features and VC++ in Visual Studio does not support it.

See this for a list of C++ features which VS2010 and VS2012 C++ compilers implement:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx