# Error with range based loop in Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt

Get these errors :

```
C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ':'  
C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
```

Here is code:

```
 void MainWindow::PrintDir(const QString &str)
    {
        QDir mDir(str);
        QString buffer;
        for(QFileInfo temp :  mDir.entryInfoList()) //first error
        {                                           //second error
            buffer += temp.absoluteFilePath() + "\n";
        }
        ui->textEdit->setText(buffer);
    }
```

I guess the reason is C++ standard? I try to include him in pro file like this `CONFIG += c++11` but nothing happen and still get same errors. Whats wrong?

**UPD**:
[image]

Comment: whats your compiler?

Comment: @Nazar554 from the error `ID`s it's seems it's `cl`?

Comment: Why not just use Qt's foreach loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898859/does-msvc10-visual-studio-2010-support-c-range-based-loops), it seems like `MSVC 2010` *doesn't* support `C++ 11` [range-based for loops](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for). This is why you get this error. I recommend you upgrade to `MSVC 2012` if you want to use `C++11 range-based for loops`.

Comment: Technically that's the compiler used to build the Qt libs used by Creator. The compiler OP's using to compile his/her snipped may be a totally different one.

Comment: @peppe I doubt it, the error code he gets is from VS and only 2010 and lower have issues with range-based for (not to mention that linking anything but pure C across Visual Studio versions is asking for trouble in the first place)

Comment: @peppe You are right! But considering the complexity level of the error he's getting makes me think that he just installed `Qt 5.3.2 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2010, OpenGL, 539 MB)` from `qt-project.org` which uses the `Qt Creator` compiled with the same version of `Qt` it uses. If this is not true I'm waiting to provide more info but I'm 99% sure this is what happened.

Comment: @PeterT: I'm not saying *"the compiler used cannot possibly be MSVC 2010"* :-) I'm saying that the compiler you see in that dialog may be different from the one OP is using to compile the program.

Comment: Thx. But now how to include 2012 to Qt?

Comment: @ratojakuf You need to install `Microsoft Visual Studio 2012` or later and add it to `Qt Creator`'s kits. Or simpler: install `Microsoft Visual Studio 2012` or later and then install `Qt 5.3.2 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2012, OpenGL, 555 MB)` or later from `qt-project.org`. Just beware: if you install `VS 2013` you need to install also the `VS 2013` version of `Qt`. These things have to match.

Comment: I have installed VS 2012 and in Qt Creator's kits add new with msvc 2012 compiler but when i created new project and build it i got this :  error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1600' doesn't match value '1700'  http://i.imgur.com/nFTgJVB.png

Comment: Try to `Build->Rebuild All`. Possible answers could be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19575747/error-lnk2038-mismatch-detected-for-msc-ver-value-1600-doesnt-match-valu

Comment: Now work. Just did what you said :    

 >You need to install Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 or later and add it to Qt Creator's kits. Or simpler: install Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 or later and then install Qt 5.3.2 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2012, OpenGL, 555 MB) or later from qt-project.org Thank you again).